# Preload css background images specified in keyframes

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am using css animations to accomplish cross fade like

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box}

.slides {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: tomato;
  animation: images 9s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes images {
  0% {
    background: url('https://fillmurray.com/300/300')
  }
  
  50% {
   background: url('http://www.placecage.com/c/300/300');
  }
  
  100% {
    background: url('https://stevensegallery.com/300/300')
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slides"></div>
```

It seems like the browser (using chrome) does not preload images, (in the first animation cycle, the transitions are not smooth).

How do I preload them in the best way and why is the browser not doing it already?

Comment: It is not doing it automatically because it can't say with 100% that the images will be needed. It wants to save the user from unnecessary loading times. You can bypass this with preloading the images via javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You should send headers to preload the images:
If using php:

```
<?php 
header('Link: <https://fillmurray.com/300/300>; rel=preload; as=image, <http://www.placecage.com/c/300/300>; rel=preload; as=image, <https://stevensegallery.com/300/300>; rel=preload; as=image');
?>
```

The same can be accomplished with  elements in the head, but this is even earlier for the browser.
Also, if interested, look into HTTP/2 push (if your server supports it). It also uses headers, and works in the same manner in that regard, although images should be coming from your own server then.

Comment: No, both can be used according to the resource you mention. Cite "

    The resource declaration is visible via HTTP headers or HTML markup, which allows the user agent to initiate the fetch earlier, and without blocking on JavaScript execution."

Comment: Interesting information, but I will go for a css only solution, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You could preload them in .slides div and hide them.

```
.slides {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url('https://fillmurray.com/300/300') no-repeat -9999px -9999px,
                url('http://www.placecage.com/c/300/300') no-repeat -9999px -9999px,
                url('https://stevensegallery.com/300/300') no-repeat -9999px -9999px;
    animation: images 9s linear 0s infinite alternate;
```

}

Comment: That is however not a pure css background solution, because I need to have one div per slide.